# npm already installed but then says "command not found"

Tags: bash, npm, osx-yosemite

I keep having this problem so I uninstalled homebrew and tried to uninstall npm, but it did not work. I installed homebrew again and then typed "brew install npm." It returned "Warning: node-0.12.7 already installed." I then tried to use npm with the following command: "npm install -g mup" and it returned "-bash: npm: command not found."

I have trouble uninstalling npm because on the site it uses npm to uninstall npm... Otherwise, it denies me permission. How can I get around this so that I can install mup with "npm install -g mup"? What's weird is that it was working earlier but now it is failing me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
cd ~
sudo rm -rf .npm
brew update
brew uninstall npm
brew install npm
```

Comment: After "brew uninstall npm"     I got this: Uninstalling     /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7... (9 files, 132K)
    Error: Permission denied -     /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.12.7/include/node/uv-private/ngx-queue.h       I appreciate the help!

Comment: `sudo chown -R username /usr/local` and `brew link --overwrite node`